# Command-Line FTP/HTTP download manager that supports multiple connections

Tags: command-line, download-manager

I'm looking for a command-line download manager that can:

- Download from FTP and HTTP
- Open several TCP connections to accelrate the download
- Supports resuming

It would be nice if it had ports to Windows & Linux, but it's not a strict requirement. It doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 3):

**See: Aria2**, I've had a bit of time with it and think it's pretty neat. Couldn't get it to torrent well, but that's more likely my internet.

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)? Doesn't support several connections, but it's a brilliant downloader regardless, and has windows and linux ports.

Opening multiple connections isn't as great as it sounds, anyway. If the server you're downloading from doesn't cap the speeds it's useless, and if it does it probably does so for a reason - meaning you're likely to annoy the administrator, possibly to the lengths of an IP ban (which would limit your connection speeds a lot more than only having one connection ;))

[Aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) looks to support it, but I've always been happy with wget.

Comment: I've always used download managers such as GetRight and FlashGet to speed up my downloading speed, and I've never been banned.

Comment: Regardless, the limits are there for a reason, and bypassing them won't make whoever put them there happy. Aria2 is really quite good, though, I might stick with it.

Comment: Aria2 is exactly what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[LFTP](http://lftp.yar.ru/)

As for porting it to windows you might want to try Cygwin, there was once a windows binary but it is no longer at the link I have for it.

Answer (score 0):

[NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)

> is a set of FREE application programs
>   implementing the File Transfer
>   Protocol (FTP).
>
> The program has been in service on
>   UNIX systems since 1991 and is a
>   popular alternative to the standard
>   FTP program, /usr/bin/ftp. NcFTP
>   offers many ease-of-use and
>   performance enhancements over the
>   stock ftp client, and runs on a wide
>   variety of UNIX platforms as well as
>   operating systems such Microsoft
>   Windows and Apple Mac OS X.