# Download with Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, download

Is there a built-in command for downloading a file using the command line on Windows? I know I can get cygwin and install wget, but I would like a solution that works on any windows PC.

Comment: What is your source - FTP?  Network share?

Comment: Given the specific `wget` mention, HTTP/S is a pretty fair assumption.

Comment: potential duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line .. http://superuser.com/questions/63664/command-line-ftp-http-download-manager-that-supports-multiple-connections .. http://superuser.com/questions/129269/download-a-file-via-http-from-a-script-in-windows .. http://superuser.com/questions/117731/download-a-file-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing for HTTP downloads on the command line built into Windows.  You could script ftp.exe for, well, FTP downloads.  You'll need a 3rd party program for HTTP though.  No need to go all the way to installing Cygwin though, you can get [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: nothing built-in?  well [there's BITS](http://superuser.com/questions/129269/download-a-file-via-http-from-a-script-in-windows); you might need to [grab *bitscontrol* from MSDN, but it is a Microsoft tool. i wouldn't be sure there isn't a way to script with VBscript or Powershell either (without any additional executable components that is).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**Wget for Windows**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), it can do this and a whole lot more. No need for a cygwin installation.