# How to download from a direct link using batch files and Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, batch, download, batch-file

I want to create a batch file which is capable of downloading any files from direct links.

I already tried this:

```
chrome start http://dl2.romhustler.net/download/MTOeeo3FWffukwoWvagsXw/1430069124/psx_full/Dino%20Crisis%20%5BU%5D%20%5BSLUS-00922%5D.rar
```

The commands are all in the same line and I tried with quotes and without quotes.

I always get a `Forbidden 403` error.

However when I copy and past the link in search bar the file starts downloading without any issue.

Is there any way to make this work?

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

Comment: If you have same problem via www browser , change your IP address, your IP address is blocked.

Comment: Does it have to be via Chrome? Otherwise there are just so many duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/138469/download-with-windows-command-line, http://superuser.com/questions/117731/download-a-file-in-a-batch-file, http://superuser.com/questions/129269/download-a-file-via-http-from-a-script-in-windows, http://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line, http://superuser.com/questions/63664/command-line-ftp-http-download-manager-that-supports-multiple-connections ...

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre to want to do it using Chrome rather than wget but it Works for me

The format is Chrome URL,  (you wrote start there in between which you shouldn't)

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http:// dl2.romhustler.net/download/MTOeeo3FWffukwoWvagsXw/1430069124/psx_full/Dino%20Crisis%20%5BU%5D%20%5BSLUS-00922%5D.rar <ENTER>
```

And it started downloading in Chrome

Comment: First I wanna thank u for ur replay but it doesn't work I get 403 Forbidden.                  Iwanted to create a direct link download frol a batch file so I can send them to my friends and when they double click it the file start downloading

Comment: @mounirgamer  it works for me.  What if you just enter that URL in the address bar in Chrome, do you get a 403 there too?